# I Want to Make a POST Request to My Local JSON File. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

Image below is a component I prepared with Redux.
I'm getting the data through the API and printing it on my Card component. I have a heart button on top of my Card component. When the user clicks this button, I want the data on that card to be posted. I'm new to React and I hope I was able to explain my problem.

[image: example component]

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchBusiness } from '../actions'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import axios from 'axios'

const truncateOverview = (string, maxLength) => {
    if (!string) return null;
    if (string.lenght <= maxLength) return string;
    return `${string.substring(0, maxLength)}...`;
}
const truncateOverview1 = (string, maxLength) => {
    if (!string) return null;
    if (string.lenght <= maxLength) return string;
    return `${string.substring(0, maxLength)}`;
}



  

  
const axiosPostCall = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:3002/news',  {
      title: "My post title",
      body: "My post content."
      })
      console.log(`data: `, data)
   
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`error: `, error)
    }
  }
axiosPostCall()


    
class BusinessList extends React.Component {
      async componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchBusiness();

    }

     handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('You clicked submit.');
      }


    renderList() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row" >
                    {this.props.business.map((value) => (
                        <div className="col-lg-3" key={value.id = uuidv4()} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <div className="card mb-5 shadow-sm">
                                <div className="card-sl">
                                    <div className="card-image">
                                        <img src={value.urlToImage === null ? value.urlToImage="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/global-news-icon-world-logo-black-white-background-simple-vector-143330934.jpg" : value.urlToImage } height={200} width={300}   alt="logo gelmiyor" class="center-block"  />
                                    </div>
                                    <a className="card-action-business"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2107/2107845.png" 
                                     onClick={axiosPostCall()} height={25} alt="logo gelmiyor" class="center-block"  /></a>
                                    <div className="card-heading">
                                        {truncateOverview(value.title, 50)}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-text">
                                        {truncateOverview(value.description, 75)}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-text" style={{color : "#061ea7af"}}>
                                    Source: {truncateOverview1( value.author === null ? value.author = 'Unidentified Source' : value.author && value.author.indexOf("https://www.") ? value.author.replace("https://www.") : value.author , 30)}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-text text-center" >
                                        <hr />
                                        {value.publishedAt.substr(11, 14).slice(0, -4)}
                                        <br />
                                        {value.publishedAt.substr(7, 10).slice(1, -7)}.{value.publishedAt.substr(5, 8).slice(0, -6)}.{value.publishedAt.substr(0, 5).slice(0, -1)}
                                    </div>
                                    <a href={value.url} className="card-button-business" target="_blank" rel='noreferrer'> Show More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.renderList()}</div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { business: state.business }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchBusiness })(BusinessList);
```

Comment: You cannot post to a JSON file. You need an endpoint which accepts JSON and then writes to a file/database.

Comment: You might be interested in something like [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)